# How to disable log for the Context

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I upgraded to .net core 2.2 and EF 2.2 as well. Now when i fetch a table from DbSet, for each row i have in my table there a log line and it's taking forever. How to disable this since i didnt have this logs in .net core 2.0 ?

ex : for the log line i have this for each row :

```
[15:58:02 DBG] Context 'BookContext' started tracking 'Book' entity.
 Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see key values.
```

And since my table has 23000 records, i have 23000 log line as well !

My serilog log config looks like this :

```
"Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Debug"
            }
        },
```

Comment: just turn down `Microsoft.*` to warning or information.

Comment: How you do that ? for now i have this "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Debug"
            }
        },

Comment: just change the Microsoft property

Comment: You need to turn off logging for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking` category. Probably something like `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking": "None"`

Answer (score 2):

you can make like this

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Override": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Error",
        "Microsoft": "Debug",
        }
    },
```

Comment: Still logging each record as before

Answer (score 1):

I use below config in my appsettings.json. @Khaled's answer was having wrong level of json format. Thank you it helps.

I hope this will help someone who end up on this thread.

My config was like below:

```
"Serilog": {
"Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" ],
"MinimumLevel": "Debug",
"Override": {
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Error",
  "Microsoft": "Debug"
},
```